# What is the "tofu scale"?

Tags: version-control

Some people have mentioned (e.g. [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311849/using-the-tofu-scale-with-svn)) the "tofu scale" when talking about branches of source code.  What is the scale and what do values on it represent?  Do you guys use it, and are there any circumstances when it is especially useful?

Thanks!

Comment: This is almost exactly the same question as was asked in the question you linked. The discussion should be there, not here. Voting to close.

Comment: Randolpho - I thought the discussion there was "Can you use it with SVN?" rather than "What is it?".  That's why I posted the question here, as I thought it'd be useful to have the definition separated out from its use in a particular SCM.

Comment: P.S. Have just rechecked the question I linked to and seen it's been updated with details on what the tofu scale is.  When I asked this question there was no explanation there at all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Tofu Scale" is a way of measuring how firm or soft a given code branch is. It was created by Laura Wingerd. You can read more about it in her book [Practical Perforce](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596101855/).